# Angular iFrame methods

Tags: angularjs, iframe, element, directive

I'm trying to make an Angular directive to wrap an iFrame. Because IE 11 doesn't support the srcdoc attribute I looked for a different way to fill the iFrame:

```
angular
    .module('angularApp')
    .directive('easyframe', easyframe);

function easyframe() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {content: '='},
        replace: true,
        template: '<iframe id="easyframe" width="100%"></iframe>',
        controller: function ($sce, $scope, $element) {
            $scope.$watch('content', function () {
                var content = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.content);
                var iframeDocument = $element[0];

                iframeDocument.open('text/html', 'replace');
                iframeDocument.write(content);
                iframeDocument.close();
             });
        }
    };
}
```

This fails because the $element I get is a Angular jQueryLite object that doesn't have the open method. How do I get to the DOM element the Angular way, so without using querySelector?

Comment: I got the wrong conclusion, the actual iFrame DOM element is at element[0].contentWindow.document.

Can I answer and/or "close" my own question in anyway?

Comment: just answer your own question - [that is fine](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 3):

I ran across a similar problem, but wanted to be able to have the content that is injected into the iframe still be bound to the containing angular scope. I wrote a directive to handle this, which can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KRfAyc5haHyFq7FyCnxg?p=preview

It is used like so:

```
<wrap-in-frame frame-template="frame-template.html" frame-selector="div" height="200" style="border-width: 5px; width: 100%;">
  Angular Interpolated Data: {{ data }}
  <div>NgModel Data Binding: <input ng-model="data" type="text" /></div>
</wrap-in-frame>

<div>
  Outside frame binding:
  <input ng-model="data" type="text" />
</div>
```

And produces the following:

[image: Frame Wrapping Example]

The `frame-template` and `frame-selector` are optional. They allow loading a file (specified by `frame-template`) into the frame and injecting the content into an element in the frame, specified by `frame-selector`.