# Access Angular Directive Inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have an iFrame that is loaded and contained inside a page that includes some angular scope.  This is all same domain  stuff.  I am unable to access the scope inside the iFrame, which leads me to believe it is part of the problem for not being able to use on of my angular directives that works throughout the rest of the (non iframe) app.

My question is, how can I use a directive that I typically just apply an attribute for inside this iFrame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to bind ng-model or a factory to an iframe in design mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237904/is-there-a-way-to-bind-ng-model-or-a-factory-to-an-iframe-in-design-mode)

Comment: You could probably use something like what I wrote in the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941722/angular-iframe-methods/36757253#36757253 , which can be found at http://plnkr.co/edit/KRfAyc5haHyFq7FyCnxg?p=preview . In my case, the content of the frame is specified in the containing frame, but it would be fairly easy to use the existing content of the iframe and simply angularify ($compile) it from the parent window's angular scope. If you still want something like that, I could make an example directive.